# Git Sourcetree Master 2 behind

Tags: git, version-control, atlassian-sourcetree

I am still working Git and Sourcetree out and am having trouble understanding how my Master branch is 2 behind my current branch which purports to be the master branch.

When I try to merge the master in to my current branch it says it is uptodate.

[image]

Can anyone explain to me how I got in to this situation and better yet, how I can get master up to date and work from it?

Thanks

EDIT: So I did as asked below, Checkout the master branch and pulled and that seems to have got it up to date except for the last few commits seem to have gone. Does anyone know why?

[image]

Comment: I do not use your particular GUI but it looks to me like the first graph is showing you a "detached HEAD" situation. Here, commits you make have no name (well, no name other than "HEAD"). You will change heads as you switch branches, and thus forget them. To *remember* them, give them a name.

Comment: Yeah it did say head at one point. But I thought I was checking it in against the master/origin. Was a bit confused when I comitted and was no longer against the Master branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that `master` is 2 commits behind `origin/master`.  You see that `origin/master` is on a merge commit that came after your `master` commit; that's one of the 2.  The other one is on the "other side" of the merge ("Set up bundles...").

How you got here is, someone else pushed changes to master (in the form of merging in some other branch).  You've fetched the changes from `origin` - at which point your local branch ref `origin/master` was updated - but you haven't yet merged (or pulled) them into `master`.

You can update `master` by checking out `master` and merging with `origin/master` (not `master`); or by doing a `pull` while on master (assuming tracking is set up in the expected way, which it probably is since you're getting the expected "2 behind" message).  There are other ways, but those are the ones that make the most sense for this situation.

**UPDATE**

It seems when you did this, some commits appeared to vanish from your display.  Most likely this means that your display is set up to show the history of what's currently checked out.  (This would be the default for running `git log`; I'm not sure how SourceTree determines what to show, as I use the command line almost exclusively.  It does appear from your screenshot that there's a drop-down control above the commit list, which might control what is being displayed.)

Now you want to be a little careful, because I see that you now have "uncommitted changes".  Unlike commits (which are pretty hard to *really* lose), git is not doing anything to protect you from losing these uncommitted changes.  So before doing any further checkouts, you should be sure you know what those changes are and whether they should be kept.  If they should be, you should either commit or stash them before doing further checkouts.  (At the command line, git would resist doing a checkout that would lose those changes; but again I can't speak for what SourceTree will do.)

Anyway, commits like "Fixing Log Out Bug" appear to have been created on some other branch; if you check that branch out, you should see those commits.  Or if you change your display settings to show that branch (or `--all`) you should be able to see them.

You can see the history of what you've had checked out using the reflogs.  Presumably the 3rd entry in the main reflog would be what you had checked out when creating the 1st screenshot in the question (unless you've done other checkouts (or similar operations) besides those I know about).

Comment: Hiya. Thanks for your reply. Greatly appreciated. So I checked out Master and did a pull which seems to have reverted me back to then but now all commits above Merge Branch User Login have gone. It's fine if they are lost, they were mostly test commits. But would be good to know why that is.

Comment: They aren't gone.  The default `log` output only shows the history of what's currently checked out.  So I infer that in the screenshot from your question, you had something other than `master` checked out; if you check it out again, those commits will appear again.  (Note that when you had "whatever" checked out, you *did* still see `master` and `origin/master`, because they are in the history of "whatever".)

Comment: Ah okay. Thats good then. So what do I checkout now? I can't checkout the branch I am on because it says I am already checked out and up to date with Origin/Master. Sorry about this, I will mark it as the correct answer once I have it all working.

Comment: Well, I don't guess I know what you should have checked out; like I said, I only can infer that you previously had *something* else checked out, probably a branch on which you'd made your temporary / test commits.  Will update with a few more details...

Comment: Thankyou for your help. I couldnt get them back (I think they were a head commit?) but I have everything running off of Master again and it took me 5 minutes to do the work which was lost so all in all I am happy with that.

Comment: Hm.. if you mean that you were in detached HEAD state when creating the commits, then the only (reasonable) way to recover them would be via the reflog.  But if you have the work in a usable state anyway, then the main take-away is: be careful with detached HEAD state. Branches are "light weight" enough that it's generally best to create one even for temporary commits, so that you can always recover easily